# Calculate the inverse of a matrix : system is computationally singular [error]

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix `m` :

```
(m <- matrix(c(26,14,24,14,20,42,24,42,90), 3))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   26   14   24
# [2,]   14   20   42
# [3,]   24   42   90
```

When i run `solve(m)` to calculate the inverse of the matrix, i get this error message :

```
solve(m)
```

> Error in solve.default(m) : 
>         system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.21104e-18

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you wish to find a generalized-inverse of this matrix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the columns are not linearly independent.

The first column * -1/3 + second column * 7/3 is equal to the third column.

```
-m[, 1] * 1/3 + 7/3 * m[, 2]

# [1] 24 42 90
```

Comment: Thanks @rawr for the conversion to R.

Answer (score 10):

We can see that this must be so in several ways each of which implies non-invertability:

**1)** The determinant of `m` is zero:

```
> det(m)
[1] -2.685852e-12
```

**2)** m has a zero eigenvalue, i.e. `eigen(m)$values[3]`.  Equivalently the nullspace of `m` is non-null -- it equals the 1 dimensional space spanned by `eigen(m)$vectors[, 3]`

```
> e <- eigen(m); e
$values
[1]  1.180000e+02  1.800000e+01 -6.446353e-15

$vectors
           [,1]          [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.2881854  9.486833e-01  0.1301889
[2,] -0.4116935  1.110223e-16 -0.9113224
[3,] -0.8645563 -3.162278e-01  0.3905667

> N <- e$vector[, 3]  # nullspace
> m %*% N  # shows that N is indeed mapped to zero
             [,1]
[1,] 5.329071e-15
[2,] 0.000000e+00
[3,] 0.000000e+00
```

**3)** The columns of `m` are *not* linearly independent.  In particular regressing `m[,1]` on the other columns gives a perfect fit (i.e. the fitted values equal `m[, 1]`) so from the coefficients of the linear model we have   `7 * m[,2] - 3 * m[, 3]` equals `m[, 1]`.

```
> fm <- lm(m[, 1] ~ m[, 2] + m[, 3] + 0)

> all.equal(fitted(fm), m[, 1]) # perfect fit
[1] TRUE

> coef(fm)
m[, 2] m[, 3] 
     7     -3 

> all.equal(7 * m[, 2] - 3 * m[, 3], m[, 1])
[1] TRUE
```

**4)** The cholesky decomposition has a zero on its diagonal:

```
> chol(m, pivot = TRUE)
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 9.486833 2.529822 4.4271887
[2,] 0.000000 4.427189 0.6324555
[3,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000
attr(,"pivot")
[1] 3 1 2
attr(,"rank")
[1] 2
Warning message:
In chol.default(m, pivot = TRUE) :
  the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite
```

**5)** `m` is not of full rank, i.e. the rank is less than 3:

```
> attr(chol(m, pivot = TRUE), "rank")
[1] 2
Warning message:
In chol.default(m, pivot = TRUE) :
  the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite
```

**Note:** The input is given reproducibly by:

```
m <- matrix(c(26, 14, 24, 14, 20, 42, 24, 42, 90), 3)
```

Comment: Hi, G. Grothendieck, in my case, I have encountered the same error message as "Error in solve.default(r, result$Structure) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.23118e-19“. However, if I randomly remove one column from the data, it will run successfully. Why, I found there is not one pair of the correlation between columns > 0.9. Why this should happen?

Comment: The column you removed lies in the subspace spanned by the other columns and the remaining columns are linearly independent.